# SignalR Core - requests handled sequentially

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

If I fire many requests over one connection to one hub, they will be executed sequentially by server. So there is no advance of parallism

I have three different methods in my hub

```
    public Task Test1(string invokeId)
    {
        Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Hello", $"Test1: Before Delay ... InvokeID: {invokeId}");
        Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
        Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Hello", $"Test1: After Delay ...  InvokeID: {invokeId}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task Test2(string invokeId)
    {
        Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Hello", $"Test2: Before Delay ... InvokeID: {invokeId}");
        Task.Delay(2500).Wait();
        Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Hello", $"Test2: After Delay ...  InvokeID: {invokeId}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task Test3(string invokeId)
    {
        Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Hello", $"Test3: Before Delay ... InvokeID: {invokeId}");
        Task.Delay(1250).Wait();
        Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Hello", $"Test3: After Delay ...  InvokeID: {invokeId}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I call them from client .NET application in a loop

```
_connection.SendAsync("Test1", "1").ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Test1: { t.Status }"));
_connection.SendAsync("Test2", "2").ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Test2: { t.Status }"));
_connection.SendAsync("Test3", "3").ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Test3: { t.Status }"));
```

Following On method

```
_connection.On("Hello", new Type[] { typeof(string) }, (parameters, state) =>
{
    return Console.WriteLine((string)parameters[0]);
}, _connection);
```

I got following OUTPUT

- Test1: RanToCompletion
- Test2: RanToCompletion
- Test3: RanToCompletion
- Test1: Before Delay ... InvokeID: 1
- Test1: After Delay ...  InvokeID: 1
- Test2: Before Delay ... InvokeID: 2
- Test2: After Delay ... InvokeID: 2
- Test3: Before Delay ... InvokeID: 3
- Test3: After Delay ...  InvokeID: 3

And if you look at that “Test2: Before Delay ... InvokeID: 2” will be called directly after “Test1: After Delay ...  InvokeID: 1”. It seems that only one Hub object is allowed at same time and regardless all three calls will immediately returns “RanToCompletion” they will be executed one after another.

It seems to be very specific, but I want to build an application where each graphical WPF object will call SignalR to retrieve content. If they will be called sequentially, I have to look for another solution.

What do I miss?

Comment: It's easy, don't block in your hub methods and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message will be handled sequentially by design within SignalR Core.

I searched at sources https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR. Comment at class

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher
```

function

```
public override Task DispatchMessageAsync(HubConnectionContext connection, HubMessage hubMessage)
        // Messages are dispatched sequentially and will stop other messages from being processed until they complete.
        // Streaming methods will run sequentially until they start streaming, then they will fire-and-forget allowing other messages to run.
```

So you have to create additional class which will handle your action and your Hub has to return immediately. But do not forget to pass **connectionId** to your class, so you can use **connectionId** for replies, because your original Hub is destroyed in meantime.

Comment: For anyone reading - this might not be the case anymore, if it ever was - the mentioned comment can no longer be found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`. I also couldn't find anything specific regarding this in the docs. Iirc, MS stated that we shouldn't rely on the sequence of execution - check and try for yourself before using this _idea_ of sequential execution in a real use case.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified, but if I had to guess, I'd say you're testing this locally, which probably means you're also using IIS Express. IIS Express is single-threaded, so multiple simultaneous requests will *always* be queued, since a thread is needed to process each request.

As for why your `RanToCompletion` logs are coming first, you haven't provided any code that actually logs that. As a result, I again have to take a stab in the dark. Most likely you're not properly awaiting the asynchronous tasks before that message is being logged. The tasks themselves, then will run and complete whenever they complete, but the calling code moves on and hits your `RanToCompletion` logging line before that occurs.

**EDIT**

Actually, I see now where `RanToCompletion` comes in. It must be the value of `t.Status`. The code in your async methods returns immediately, because you're not awaiting anything inside. The contained async tasks are kicked off, but have not completed yet by the time the method returns. Then, your `ContinueWith` lambda is run, and afterwards the tasks inside complete and log the other messages.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Yes RanToCompletion comes from t.Status. But this is behaviour I expected. At the client I want to send "request" and go forward (example GUI). But at the server the request will be handled sequentially one after the other. As you can see Test3 is waiting only a 1/4 of Test1. But during debugging you see that Test3 is called after Test2 after Test1. Thank you for your tipp with IIS Express. I will check this with IIS on a separated server today. Do you know special settings I have to check?

Comment: No. It's just a simple matter of single vs multi-threaded. Should work fine on full IIS.

Comment: Chris, it will be handled sequentially. I found this in a comment within sources of SignalR Core. Do you have an idea how to write this in this request and mark this as solved? Do I edit the original request or add a new answer?